# Print several arrays as columns

Tags: python

I am trying to print a list of arrays where each array is a column. I have the following arrays:

```
cat=['aba','vdv']
dog=['tul','baba']
```

I can accomplish what I want by doing the following:

```
for x in zip(cat,dog):
    print '\t'.join(x)

aba tul
vdv baba
```

But this is cumbersome if I want to add many more columns, so I'd like to be able to set `cat` and `dog` to a single variable and then iterate over that variable, and print out each array as a column in a table like this:

```
cat=['aba','vdv']
dog=['tul','baba']
df=[cat,dog]

for x in zip(df):
    print '\t'.join(x)
```

However that produces an error. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `for x in zip(*df)`.

Comment: What you try to do includes (matrix) *transposition*

Answer (score 0):

`zip` receives iterables as separate arguments, not in a list. When using `zip(df)`, you are actually passing a single iterable to zip (`[cat, dog]`). Compare:

```
zip(cat, dog)  # what you should do
zip([cat, dog])  # what you are doing
```

In the first case, `cat` and `dog` are considered separate iterables, so `x` has these values during each iteration:

1. `('aba', 'tul',)  # (cat[0], dog[0])`
2. `('vdv', 'baba')  # (cat[1], dog[1])`

In the second case `[cat, dog]` is considered a single iterable, so `x` has these values during every iteration:

1. `(['aba', 'vdv'],)  # [cat, dog][0]`
2. `(['tul', 'baba'],)  # [cat, dog][1]`

To pass every item of the list as a separate argument, you have to unpack the list into separate arguments:

```
cat = ['aba', 'vdv']
dog = ['tul', 'baba']
df = [cat, dog]

for x in zip(*df):  # note the asterisk before df
    print('\t'.join(x))  # using Python 3, so added parenthesis
```

You could also have replaced the loop with this:

```
print(*('\t'.join(x) for x in zip(*df)), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, just missing the unpacking in your call to zip.

```
cat = ['aba', 'vdv']
dog = ['tul', 'baba']
df = [cat, dog]

for x in zip(*df):
    print('\t'.join(x))
```

You could also do it without a for loop, like this:

```
print(*map('\t'.join,zip(*df)),sep='\n')
```